# asp.net mvc - how do I know that a partial has been reloaded?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc application that uses partial views.
How do I know that a partial view has been reloaded, I want to apply a jquery widgit to a table?

This is the top of my partial:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<MvcDataProvider.Models.InheritedItem>>"%>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Areas/Family/JQuery/vucFamilyManufactors.js")%>'></script>

<div id="divManufactorsTable">
    <table id="tblManufactorTable" class="pretty-table double-both">
```

This is my jquery that has to be applied when the partial is reloaded:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divManufactorsTable').SelectTable();
});
```

The way I got around this up to now is by using the script tag in the partial. That would then apply the ready function when the partial was reloaded.. I want to stop using this approach as I want to use the partial in multiple places and the script tag is making things complicated. I want to control the functionality from the page and not the partial.

Please note that applying the script itself in the partial is not an option, As there is much more code that I use in the document ready event.

I hope I got things across clearly, Thanks

Comment: How do you load your partialview ?

Comment: What do you mean the partial gets "reloaded?"

Comment: Forgot to say partial is loaded via the jquery.load() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are loading the partial view. If it's done on the server as a sort of inline view rendering then just putting the javascript in the parent view and using the typical jquery document ready would work fine. if you're loading the partial view using ajax, you should use the same javascript but as part of the success logic on the ajax call.

Comment: Thanks, That was so simple I just added logic to the load function.